# Taking a new line in a label when reading the text to add to the label from a text file

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to read a sentence from a text file, however, it runs off the side of the screen when I apply that sentence to a label. I would like to take a new line a couple of times but I am not sure how to do this in my situation.

I tried placing multiple '\n's into the text file but they show up as actual text in the label and don't provide a new line.

```
List<string> questions = new List<string>();
questions = File.ReadAllLines("questions.txt").ToList();
label1.Text = questions[0]; // this question cuts off the side of the screen from the label. \n shows in the text
```

I'd simply like to be able to take a new line in the label but I am not sure how to do this. Thank you for reading about my issue.

How might I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following

```
label1.MaximumSize = new Size(label1.Width, 0);
label1.AutoSize = true;
label1.Text = questions[0];
```

This would wrap your text.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @itzgeez Glad to help you. Kindly mark it as answer if it helped you resolve the issue, so that it can be helpful for others too.